# Determining orthogonal polygons in a 3D integer lattice

Tags: python, python-3.x

The last couple of days I've been trying to get a simple algorithm for uniquely determining orthogonal polygons in 3D integer space, having already determined coplanar points.

By the time we got here we know each point is unique and there are no collinear points.

For example, given the coplanar points `pts` (lists or tuples)

```
    pts = [
        [0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0], [4, 1, 0],
        [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0], [4, 2, 0],
        [0, 3, 0], [4, 3, 0]
    ]

# Generate orthogonal polygons
# 3 +-----------+
#   |           |
# 2 |  +__+  +--+
#   |  |  |  |
# 1 |  +--+  +__+
#   |           |
# 0 +-----------+
#   0  1  2  3  4

#    result = [
#       [
#         [0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 2, 0], 
#         [3, 2, 0], [3, 1, 0], [4, 1, 0], [4, 0, 0]
#       ], [
#         [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]
#       ]
#    ]
```

I found the basis of an algorithm for this [in a paper](http://www.science.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/Papers/OrthoConnect.pdf) as authored by [Joseph O'Rourke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387778/joseph-orourke)
The following seems to work for the few tests I set up (however it doesn't deal with orientation).

```
def polygonise(pts: list) -> list:
    # axes gives us the varying columns (we can ignore z for this)
    axes = {i:set(c) for i,c in enumerate(zip(*pts)) if len(set(c))!=1}
    a, b = axes.keys()

    # construct dicts of axis-columns 
    pts_by_axis = {axis: {col: [] for col in cols} for axis,cols in axes.items()}
    for pt in pts:
        for axis in axes:
            pts_by_axis[axis][pt[axis]].append(pt)

    # each axis-column (sorted by the other dimension)
    # will now be paired off into edges, and constructed into axis-edge-dicts
    edges = {}
    for axis in axes:
        other = a if axis != a else b
        for col,pt_list in pts_by_axis[axis].items():
            pt_list.sort(key=lambda p:p[other])
            for i in range(0,len(pt_list),2):
                v1 = tuple(pt_list[i])
                v2 = tuple(pt_list[i + 1])
                edges[tuple((axis,v1))] = other, v2
                edges[tuple((axis,v2))] = other, v1


    # now derive the polygons, starting at any point.
    axis, edge = next(iter(edges.keys()))
    result, poly = [], [edge]

    while edges:
        if (axis, edge) not in edges:
            # This polygon is now closed. keep it, and move to the next one.
            result.append(poly[:-1])  # if wanted looped, don't slice
            poly = []
            axis, edge = next(iter(edges.keys()))
        else:
            # Get the next edge. change the axis (edge is on a different axis)
            axis, new_edge = edges.pop((axis,edge))
            # delete any old reversed edge.
            del edges[(axis, edge)]
            edge = new_edge

        # add the edge to the existing polygon
        poly.append(edge)
    # capture the final polygon.
    result.append(poly[:-1]) # if wanted looped, don't slice.
    return result



if __name__ == "__main__":
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from random import shuffle
    pts = [
        (0, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0),
        (1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (4, 1, 0),
        (1, 2, 0), (2, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0), (4, 2, 0),
        (0, 3, 0), (4, 3, 0)
    ]
    # shuffle just to make it different.
    shuffle(pts)
    result = polygonise(pts)
    # all the below is just to show the result
    fig = plt.figure()
    subplot = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    subplot.axis('off')
    subplot.scatter([0.6, 3.1], [0.7, 3.3], [0, 0], alpha=0.0)
    subplot.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(result, edgecolors='k', facecolors='b', linewidths=1, alpha=0.2))
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image: result]

I think that the loops could be easier, and I'm not convinced that I need to store edges twice, (which means I have to delete the unused one).

Any ideas for tidying the `polygonise()` method would be welcome.

J. O'Rourke, "Uniqueness of orthogonal connect-the-dots", *Computational Morphology*, G.T. Toussaint (editor), Elsevier Science Publishers, B.V.(North-Holland), 1988, 99-104. [found here](http://www.science.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/Papers/OrthoConnect.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your latest edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher, thanks - no convention was meant to be broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Type Hints

+1 for using type hints.  But they could be a little more informative.

`def polygonise(pts: list) -> list:`

Ok.  The function takes a `list` of `pts`, but what are `pts`?  It returns a list, but a list of what?

```py
from typing import Sequence

Point = Sequence[int]
Polygon = list[Point]

def polygonise(points: list[Point]) -> list[Polygon]:
    ...
```

Now we're giving the reader a lot of information.  A point is a sequence of integers.  Could be a `tuple`, could be a `list`.  Not important.  Instead of `pts`, we're a bit more explicit and say `points`.  Finally, the function returns a specific kind of `list`: a `Polygon` list.

You can help the reader out even more by including a nice `"""docstring"""` for the function.

## Axes

`axes = {i:set(c) for i,c in enumerate(zip(*pts)) if len(set(c))!=1}`

I really, really hate this statement.  It takes the list of points, and explodes each point as an argument for `zip`.  Then, it takes the first coordinate of each of those points, and returns it as a `tuple`.  `enumerate` adds an index to this, to keep track of which coordinate axis we are processing.  Then, we assign those to things to `i, c` ... really opaque variable names.  `axis, coordinates` might be clearer.  Then we turn the coordinates into a `set`, determine the `len` of the set, and if that is not 1, we turn the coordinates into a `set` again, for construction the dictionary.

Yikes!  That's a lot to unpack.

Then we take the axes, and assign it into to variables `a` and `b`, hoping there are exactly 2 axis.

Perhaps we should add some error checking.

```py
    num_coord = len(points[0])
    if any(len(pt) != num_coord for pt in points):
        raise ValueError("All points should have the same number of coordinates")

    axes = ...

    if len(axes) != 2:
        raise ValueError("All coordinates must be in an orthogonal 2D plane")

    a, b = axes.keys()
```

That gives me a lot more confidence in the code.

I still don't like the `axes = ...` statement.  I would re-write it, and maybe use the walrus operator (`:=`) to avoid creating the set twice, but I'm about to significantly change it.

## Useless code

`edges[tuple((axis,v1))] = other, v2`

Here, `(axis, v1)` is creating a tuple, to pass to the `tuple(...)` function.  That seems ... odd.  You could simplify it to:

`edges[axis, v1] = other, v2`

## Alternate implementation

### Axes

Instead of a dictionary, let's just extract a list of axis which have varying coordinate data.  A simple comparison of each coordinate of all points with the coordinate of the first point, for each coordinate, will tell us if that axis is important or not.

```py
    axes = [axis for axis, first in enumerate(points[0])
            if any(pt[axis] != first for pt in points)]

    if len(axes) != 2:
        raise ValueError("All coordinates must be in an orthogonal 2D plane")

    a, b = axes
```

This is a much simpler concept.  No sets are being created (twice).  No dictionaries.

### Sorted Edges

The `pts_by_axis` is very complex, a dictionary of dictionaries of arrays.

Let's rework this, by simply sorting the `points` list.  We'll sort it two ways, first by the `(a, b)` coordinate, then by the `(b, a)` coordinate.  We'll use a helper function to generate the sort keys:

```py
def point_key(first: int, second: int):
    def key(pt):
        return pt[first], pt[second]
    return key
```

Now we can say `sorted(points, key=point_key(a, b))`, and we'll have the points sorted in one direction.  `sorted(points, key=point_key(b, a))` will sort it in the other direction.

Since the points always come in pairs, to form edges, let's add another helper function, to extract pairs of points from the sorted array.

```py
def in_pairs(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    return zip(it, it)
```

With these, we can build our sorted edge structure.  But instead of keying the `edges` dictionary with a tuple to encoding the axis of the edge, let's just use two dictionaries:

```py
    a_edge = {}
    for v1, v2 in in_pairs(sorted(points, key=point_key(a, b))):
        a_edge[v1] = v2
        a_edge[v2] = v1

    b_edge = {}
    for v1, v2 in in_pairs(sorted(points, key=point_key(b, a))):
        b_edge[v1] = v2
        b_edge[v2] = v1
```

The loop at the end does some check to close a polygon and start the next one.  Really, you have two loops.  Loop while there are still edges.  Inside that loop, loop until you've made a polygon.  With that structure, the code reads much better:

```py
    result = []
    while a_edge:
        v1 = next(iter(a_edge.keys()))
        poly = []

        while v1 in a_edge:
            v2 = a_edge.pop(v1)
            v3 = b_edge.pop(v2)
            a_edge.pop(v2)
            b_edge.pop(v1)
            poly.extend((v1, v2))
            v1 = v3

        result.append(poly)
        
    return result
```

Note that I use `poly = []` instead of `poly = [v1]`, which means no slice is required at the end to remove the extra point.

Also, I'm popping `v2` out of the `a_edge` dictionary, not a `edge`, since what is popped out is just a vertex.  I find that much clearer.

Comment: Brilliant contribution, @AJNeufeld.  I'm going to extend the question to include your answers - I'm not sure if that's the right way of 'responding'..

Comment: I got my knuckles rapped.  Never mind - your answer is good enough for me.

Comment: @Konchog If your code has significantly improved, you can post a new question (with your new code) tomorrow. Feel free to add a hyperlink to your old question for bonus context.